# curve_fit of a summation of functions

Tags: python, model-fitting

For my bachelor's thesis I need to fit a Generalized Maxwell Function. The function goes as follows:

[image]

I get the data (x,y) from a .csv file and use it to `curve_fit`.

Currently I'm working on a 1st order fit (so i filled the formula in with N = 1 to make it easier for myself). I don't know how to add extra parts of the summation to my function and fit all the extra parameters as well. I know that N will have a maximum value of 10.

```
def first_order(G_0, G_1, t_1, omega):
    return G_0 * ((G_1*t_1*omega)/(1+(t_1**2)*(omega**2)))


def calc_gmm(dframe):
    array_omega = np.array(dframe['Angular Frequency']).flatten()
    array_G = np.array(dframe['Loss Modulus']).flatten()

    print(array_omega)
    print(array_G)
    variables, _ = curve_fit(first_order, array_omega, array_G, p0=[1,5,0.5])
    print(variables)
    print(_)

    plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
    plt.plot(array_omega, array_G)
    plt.plot(array_omega, first_order(variables[0], variables[1], variables[2], array_omega))
    plt.show()
```

This is some sample data.
[image: Sample data]

This is the fixed result (after help from SO).
[image: Result of the fit]

Comment: Shouldn't tau be an array, and not omega? In your function, you should use G_1[i] and t_1[i], and sum over i. N can be transfered as an extra parameter to curve_fit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rheology! I did my PhD thesis on this, and I fitted many Maxwell models. Here's my recommendations to you.

First, are both G' and G'' of interest to you, or only G''? I typically had to fit both, and, for better results, the relaxation times and moduli had to be the same on both G' and G'', so I think you have to change your approach to consider this.

Second, I think that a package like `lmfit` is better to do this because you have more control over the minimization function.

Third, since `n` is an integer, I think you have to evaluate your models at `n=1`, `n=2`, ..., `n=10` and check the standard errors of your parameters. Too much is overfitting and too little is underfitting. Can't really automate this I think.

Let's first construct some toy data.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import lmfit

def G2Prime(g_i, t_i, w):  # G''
    return g_i * (t_i * w) / (1 + t_i ** 2 * w **2)

def GPrime(g_i, t_i, w):   # G'
    return g_i * (t_i * w)**2 / (1 + t_i ** 2 * w **2)

# Generate a sample model with 3 components
omegas = np.logspace(-2, 1)
# G0 = 1
test_data_GPrime = 1 + GPrime(1, 1, omegas) + GPrime(1, 10, omegas) + GPrime(1, 30, omegas)
test_data_G2Prime = 1 + G2Prime(1, 1, omegas) + G2Prime(1, 10, omegas) + G2Prime(1, 30, omegas)
```

Here's the graph.

[image: Initial]

Next, let's create the parameters to use `lmfit`.

```
params = lmfit.Parameters()  # Creates a parameter object
params.add('n', value=2, vary=False, min=1, max=10) # start with n=2, so it's not exact
params.add('G0', value=1, min=0)
for i in range(params['n'].value):   # Adds the relaxation times and moduli separately
    params.add(f't_{i}', value=1, min=0)
    params.add(f'g_{i}', value=1, min=0)
```

Then, let's define the minimization function considering both G' and G''.

```
def min_function(params, x, data_GPrime, data_G2Prime):
    n = int(params['n'].value)
    G0 = params['G0']
    # Calculate the first component
    model_GPrime = G0 + GPrime(params['g_0'], params['t_0'], x)
    model_G2Prime = G0 + G2Prime(params['g_0'], params['t_0'], x)
    for i in range(1, n): # Go through the other components
        model_GPrime += GPrime(params[f'g_{i}'], params[f't_{i}'], x)
        model_G2Prime += G2Prime(params[f'g_{i}'], params[f't_{i}'], x)
    # return the total residual of both G' and G''.
    return (model_GPrime - data_GPrime) + (model_G2Prime - data_G2Prime)
```

Lastly, let's call the minimization function. With this approach, you can't use a varying `n`, so you have to vary it yourself.

```
res = lmfit.minimize(min_function, params, args=(omegas, test_data_GPrime, test_data_G2Prime))
```

Let's see the result with `n=2`.

```
plt.plot(omegas, test_data_GPrime)
plt.plot(omegas, test_data_GPrime + res.residual, c='r', ls='--')
plt.plot(omegas, test_data_G2Prime)
plt.plot(omegas, test_data_G2Prime + res.residual, c='r', ls='--')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
```

[image: n=2]

`n=3` is a perfect fit, so I won't show it. Here's the output report of the fit, with `lmfit.report_fit(res)`.

```
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 72
    # data points      = 50
    # variables        = 5
    chi-square         = 0.04825415
    reduced chi-square = 0.00107231
    Akaike info crit   = -337.164818
    Bayesian info crit = -327.604702
[[Variables]]
    n:    2 (fixed)
    G0:   1.10713874 +/- 0.01190976 (1.08%) (init = 1)
    t_0:  1.11030322 +/- 0.02837998 (2.56%) (init = 1)
    g_0:  1.07272282 +/- 0.01532421 (1.43%) (init = 1)
    t_1:  16.6536979 +/- 0.34791430 (2.09%) (init = 1)
    g_1:  1.71017461 +/- 0.02099472 (1.23%) (init = 1)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are < 0.100)
    C(G0, g_1)  = -0.769
    C(G0, t_1)  = -0.731
    C(g_0, t_1) =  0.699
    C(t_0, g_0) =  0.497
    C(t_0, t_1) =  0.493
    C(G0, g_0)  = -0.442
    C(t_1, g_1) =  0.263
    C(t_0, g_1) = -0.255
    C(G0, t_0)  = -0.231
    C(g_0, g_1) = -0.157
```

Now, you have to iterate through the other possible `n`, check the fit parameters and determine which is ideal.

Comment: This is fantastic! If it's okay for you I would very much like to keep contact if I should have any more questions. Is that okay?

Comment: Sure thing! I would share with you some of my code, but it's mostly in portuguese so I don't think it would help you very much.

Comment: Great! Is there a way i can PM you?

Comment: In SO, not really. Just post a comment here and we can talk. If this gets long, a chat room is created automatically, I think.

Comment: i just edited the post with the result of your help. I was able to fit the GMM model on my data!!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I do have a question. How did you manage to get to this residual formula?

Comment: I don't understand. You mean the function overall, or only the return statement?

Comment: I don't know how you got to the return statement.

Comment: Look at the documentation of lmfit to see the logic to create this minimization function. https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/fitting.html What I modified was that the model would change based on how many components there are (starts with 1 element,index 0,then builds up). Last, I got the residual of G' and G'', and summed them. This way, both curves are minimized simultaneously. If you wanted to fit only one, just have to remove the other calculations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231309/discussion-between-k-cl-and-maxim-princen).

Answer (score 0):

You can make the function arguments `g` and `tau` arrays and then use `sum`.

```
def gmm(G_0, g, tau, omega):
    return G_0 * ((g*tau*omega)/(1+(tau**2)*(omega**2))).sum()
```

Example:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)
g = np.random.rand(10)
tau = np.random.rand(10)
gmm(1, g, tau, 0.5)  # returns 0.6530812207319884
```

Comment: Okay so this is definitely a good solution to the summation. But there's another problem. So in the beginning, I don't really know the values of the g's and the tau's and I also don't know how many there are going to be (only the max amount). So could i use an iteration to start at N = 1,  estimate the parameters and then N=2 ,estimate the parameters and so on?

Comment: @MaximPrincen Above definition of `gmm` works for an arbitrary array size.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that I wont know the size of the array. So for example:
firstly i do the curve_fit to calculate parameters tau_i and g_i for N=1. So: 3 variables (G_0, g_1 and tau_1). Then I do the curve_fit to calculate parameters tau_i and g_i for N=2. So: 5 variables (G_, g_1, tau_1, g_2 and tau_2). So how does the gmm curve_fit work if the function doesn't know what value N (size of arrays of tau and g) is?

Comment: @MaximPrincen Sorry, I'm not sure that I understand the problem. `curve_fit` will fit whatever the number of coefficients is you input in the function (see the documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html)). Could you provide sample data used for the fitting?

Comment: I added some sample data for the fitting. Please let me know if you don't understand something. My job is to estimate the N for which the R² value is good, but the smaller the N, the better the system. So i need to find a sweet spot for the N. That's why i need to do an iterative process starting at N=1 and developing to greater N's.

Comment: @MaximPrincen Thanks! Could you please use `dframe.to_dict()` and paste the output as text? An image is not really useful, if I want to replicate your code.

Comment: you want me to do dframe_to_dict() and print(dframe_to_dict()) ?

Comment: @MaximPrincen Nope, simply copy the output of `dframe.to_dict()` to your question's body.

Comment: gofvonx, thanks a lot! But my question has been answered. Sorry for bothering!